# Changing value of a boolean using ng-click used inside a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I am displaying some data on my html page inside a div using ng-repeat. Inside the `div` I have a button in order to hide the content of each `div` seperately.Here is a simplified version of my html file.

```
<body ng-app="task" ng-controller="repeat">
    <div ng-repeat='x in array' ng-show="{{ x.show }}">
      <p>{{ x.text }}
      </p>
  <button ng-click="toggle()">Hide</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

the code in my .js file is as follows

```
var app = angular.module('task');
app.controller('repeat',function($scope){
    $scope.array = [{
        show: true,
        text:'Sample Text 1'},
      { 
        show: true,
        text:'Sample Text 2'},
      { 
        show: true,
        text:'Sample Text 3'}];

    $scope.toggle = function(){
       $scope.array.show = false ;
      };
})
```

Can anyone suggest me the required changes so that on clicking the button inside my `div` , that particular div gets hidden.

I think I am committing a mistake in referencing the particular element of the array while calling the `function toggle()` through ng-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found a way to actually cater my needs , thank you all for your suggestions. Here is the code I actually used:

```
<body ng-app="task" ng-controller="repeat">
 <div ng-repeat='x in array' ng-hide="x.show">
  <p>{{ x.text }}
  </p>
  <button ng-click="toggle($index)">Hide</button>
 </div>
</body>
```

and in my js file I used it like this:

```
var app = angular.module('task');
app.controller('repeat',function($scope){
 $scope.array = [{
    show: true,
    text:'Sample Text 1'},
  { 
    show: true,
    text:'Sample Text 2'},
  { 
    show: true,
    text:'Sample Text 3'}];

 $scope.toggle = function(){
   $scope.array[index].show = false ;
  };
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Put your element as an argument in toggle function.

```
<button ng-click="toggle(x)">Hide</button>
```

and change it in controller like this:

```
$scope.toggle = function(x){
    x.show = !x.show;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

And easy to achieve this without calling the function in the controller:

```
<body ng-app="task" ng-controller="repeat">
  <div ng-repeat='x in array' ng-show="showDetail">
    <p>{{ x.text }}</p>
      <button ng-click="showDetail != showDetail">Hide</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

The method above will also hide the button if you click hide. If you want to hide your content and show it again, the following code can achieve that:

```
<body ng-app="task" ng-controller="repeat>
  <div ng-repeat='x in array'>
    <div class="content" ng-show="showContent">
      <p>{{ x.text }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class='btn btn-control'>
      <button ng-click="showContent != showContent"> Hide </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your html pass

```
   <button ng-click="toggle(x.$index)">Hide</button>
```

While in js

```
  $scope.toggle = function(index){
  $scope.array[index].show = !$scope.array[index].show;
  };
```