# Show/Hide items in an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

[QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073190/changing-value-of-a-boolean-using-ng-click-used-inside-a-ng-repeat)

Using the above question's code, my question is there a clean way to be able to remove all the booleans in each object and get angular to know whether to show/hide each individual repeated object.

I have a table of items that if you click a button it will flip a boolean and show it's self, but it will do this to every item in the table and not just the individual item as they are all pointing to the same boolean.

Is there a way to dynamically generate a boolean for each item? I really don't want to have to add a show item within each object to call on. There has to be a better way.
 Edit: Here is a better template to use as an example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13soaet1/2/)

HTML

```
<body ng-app="task" ng-controller="repeat">
 <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Account</td>
      <td>Details</td>
      <td>Secret</td>
      <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in accounts">
      <td>{{x.account}}</td>
      <td>{{x.details}}</td>
      <td><span>{{x.secret}}</span></td>
      <td>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Show Secret</button>
      </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('task', []);

app.controller('repeat', function($scope) {
  $scope.accounts = [{
    account: "account 01",
    details: "lorum ipsum",
    secret: 0101101,
  }, {
    account: "account 02",
    details: "lorum ipsum",
    secret: 0101101,
  }, {
    account: "account 03",
    details: "lorum ipsum",
    secret: 0101101,
  }, {
    account: "account 04",
    details: "lorum ipsum",
    secret: 0101101,
  }];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in context with question you mentioned

In your html pass

```
   <button ng-click="toggle(x.$index)">Hide</button>
```

While in js

```
  $scope.toggle = function(index){
  $scope.array[index].show = !$scope.array[index].show;
  };
```

Comment: this doesn't answer my question, this uses the show boolean. This is what I want to remove, not have to use a boolean in each and every object so that I can toggle which one can appear or not

Comment: <button ng-click="{{x.show=!x.show}}">Hide</button>

Comment: again, using x.show, I want to be able to remove show completely and not have to have that within each object.

Comment: can you make JS Fiddle for it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/13soaet1/1/ I cannot seem to get Angular to work in jsfiddle.

Comment: there is no way you cannot access array properties without index

Comment: ng-repeat does that for me, it iterates through the array and returns each object. Why would i need an index?

Comment: @MichaelLetcher your  link is not working correctlye

Comment: It's works fine for me, what is the issue? I've updated the question with the code as well.

Comment: no kidding, that's what I want to fix, are you not reading my question?

Answer (score 0):

On a button, call angularjs function to set boolean values and then use `ng-show`/`ng-hide` to toggle the view.

Comment: yes, that is what I'm going for but I want to know of a simple solution to dynamically creating all those booleans with out adding them to each object and having to store that.

Comment: please share working jsfiddle code. so that i can help you

Comment: I've added the example above,